# Wordpress 'where' => clause comparing id's

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, podscms

I am using Wordpress and PODS framework and ACF, only reason I am using ACF aswell is because it seemed logical to me as I am a front-end developer not back-end, and this just seemed like easiest way to do this.

Trying to use where clause to compare id's in an array, here is my code:

```
<?php 
  $term  = get_sub_field("featured_category"); 
  $itms  = get_sub_field("featured_items"); 
  $limit = get_sub_field("limited"); 

  global $wpdb; 

  $params = array(
    'where' => 'ID  =' . $itms->ID,
    'limit' => $limit, 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
  );
  $themes  = pods( 'themes', $params); 
?>
```

$itms returns posts that are selected in wp-admin, its an ACF field that lets the client select post items to display.

when i dump $itms it returns:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[566]
      public 'ID' => int 46
```

the above is just the top part, there are 3 post objects in that array, i am trying to return ID, i assume that should be a meta_query or something?

Hope this is making sense, struggled for hours.

But to sum up i need to check if the ids in the pods loop equal any ID $itms the rest of the loop will work fine if i can figure out how to use 'where' to compare an array of IDs.

Comment: Definitely don't use Pods AND ACF.  Anything ACF can do, Pods can do.  Using both adds complexity to any and all problems you might have.

Comment: And - as a follow-on comment - Pods is FAR harder to use.  You really do need to be a back-end developer to use Pods well.  If you don't need the functionality of Pods, I'd strongly encourage you to use ACF ONLY, or ACF and one (or even two) other "special purpose" plugins to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I always find myself using both, ACF just does some things faster, and time is money :D

Comment: I use pods + acf all the time... but I'm not clear what you're trying to do here. If you just want the id's you can have ACF only return an array of the IDs (its a radio button in the ACF interface). If you want to take those id's and display the related pod item... I tend to just use a pods shortcode to easily spit them out with the added benefit of using pods magic tags.